# Permission denied when trying to create a directory with os.makedirs on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs, macos-high-sierra

I'm working with someone else's code, and I cannot run it locally (I also cannot ask the person, who is currently unavailable). I have a `main.py` file with the following code:

```
import os
from tiger_server import constants
from tiger_server.web_server import WebServer

if not os.path.exists(constants.RESULTS_PATH):
    os.makedirs(constants.RESULTS_PATH)

WebServer.start_web_server()
```

`RESULTS_PATH` is `"/usr/share/tiger/instance"`

When I try to run `main.py` from my command line, I get the following error:

```
File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.makedirs(constants.RESULTS_PATH)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py",
line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py",
line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py",
line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/tiger'
```

It seems the code is trying to make a new directory, but how can I find it to deal with its permissions? Does it have to do with its permissions to begin with?

I have those permissions to the main.py file and its directory (ME is my username, so it seems I own the file):

```
-rw-r--r--   1 ME  staff   211 Aug 13 14:40 main.py
```

I tried disabling SIP with `csrutil disable`. Before I did this I was getting another error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/share/tiger'
```

Can someone tell me how to proceed to be able to run the file?

Comment: Users generally don't have rights to write `/usr/share`. You could do `ls -ld /usr/share` to verify and to see if there is a group other than root. You'll need some sort of elevated rights to create the directory. Perhaps this other user has added those rights or is in a group with those rights. `getfacl /usr/share` may show if additional access controls have been added to the directory.

Comment: @tdelaney When I run `ls -ld /usr/share` what I get is `drwxr-xr-x  47 root  wheel  1504 Dec 16  2019 /usr/share`. What does this mean? `getfacl /usr/share` returns command not found. I cloned the code from the project's repo, so the code creator wasn't working on my machine.

Comment: It means the directory is owned by user "root" that has full permissions and group "wheel" that only has read and scan permissions. These are the traditional unix permissions but systems typically have more sophisticated permission systems that can be used. getfacl is "get file system access control list" which, along with setfacl can be used to give fine grained user acess. But it doesn't work on all systems and I don't know macos specifically. You might find help with macos permissions on superuser.com

Comment: But the upshot is that your user doesn't have create-subdirectory permissions on /usr/share.

Comment: Does it work if you run your script as a root? It definitely should after SIP is off. Also, did you try creating the directory manually using mkdirto see what happens?